# Duplicate records in SQL

Tags: java, mysql, hashcode

Checking duplicate records by the calculating the hashcode of the table row:

I am uploading excel file into mysql database through user interface before actually inserting the records i have to identify the duplicate records against the records already present in the main table (number of records can be 2500000) and i have to do it as fast as possible.

My solution to this is I am adding one more field in the table say Hashcode and at the time of insertion of records i will calculate the hashcode for each row and at the time of checking the duplicate rows I will match only the hashcode field.If the hashcode exists in the main table then the record is duplicate else it is unique.

Is there any other way to do this in a more faster manner as i am unaware of mysql database capabilities

Thanks!

Comment: Hashing 2,500,000 records is going to add a good chunk to computation time, even if the hashing algorithm isn't a particularly strong one. Do the records not have a unique ID you can check against instead?

Comment: you can design you table in a way that you dont need to check for duplicate rows.It will be more clear to explain you if you tell us your table attributes.

Comment: 2,500,000 records are the total records in the table that already hold their own hashcode at the time of their insertion, their is no unique id the duplicate records are to be checked on certain fields

Comment: so you can make all the fields together as a primary key,that will serve the purpose,no need to create hashcode

Comment: @Amar I want to identify duplicate records and display them to the user and user will decide which one to keep and which not to keep so making them as primary key will not serve my purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) if you want to stick to the hash-code use something like

```
 SELECT sha256(CONCAT(col1, "-", col2, "-", col3)) FROM ...
```

instead of MD5() - I had some collisions here recently. Dont forget to add an index on the new column.

b) For your purpose a simple

```
 SELECT col1, col2, col3, Count(*) 
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY 1,2,3 HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

might be what you want. This will give you 100% duplicates as well and you dont have to add a new hash-col and check for it...

Comment: In b option it will solve my problem for one table but the records that i have to compare are in a different staging table

Comment: just join the other table and select cols as described.